# Spring-Batch - MultiFileResourcePartitioner - Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: spring, amazon-s3, spring-batch

I am using FlatFileItemReader and have extended the AbstractResource to return a stream from Amazon S3 object.

```
S3Object amazonS3Object = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket,file));
InputStream stream = null;
stream = amazonS3Object.getObjectContent();
return stream;
```

In my batch job I have also implemented MultiFileResourcePartitioner in which i gave the bucket to partition all the files. I am able to read only part of few files and after which i get a socket reset error.see below pieces of error

```
.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@122ba881]
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG RepeatTemplate:366 - Repeat operation about to start at count=9
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG StepContextRepeatCallback:68 - Preparing chunk execution for StepContext: org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext@252ce07a
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG StepContextRepeatCallback:76 - Chunk execution starting: queue size=0
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG ResourcelessTransactionManager:367 - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG RepeatTemplate:464 - Starting repeat context.
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG RepeatTemplate:366 - Repeat operation about to start at count=1
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG RepeatTemplate:366 - Repeat operation about to start at count=2
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG RepeatTemplate:366 - Repeat operation about to start at count=3
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG RepeatTemplate:366 - Repeat operation about to start at count=4
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG DefaultClientConnection:160 - Connection 0.0.0.0:58171<->10.37.135.39:8099 shut down
2015-08-24 23:24:03 DEBUG DefaultClientConnection:176 - Connection 0.0.0.0:58171<->10.37.135.39:8099 closed

Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.NonTransientFlatFileException: Unable to read from resource: [null]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.readLine(FlatFileItemReader.java:220)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:173)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)</i>
```

My requirement is to process files with millions of records out of an S3 bucket and the application runs on AWS. I have passed the S3 client configurations with retry's and open connections which didn't help much.

Comment: The Spring Cloud AWS project provides abstractions for obtaining a resource for S3 buckets, but it downloads them as a local resource.  Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: MM - Just to understand your point - Did you mean that I pass the S3 bucket through Spring Cloud abstractions to my MultiresourcePartitioner? Or are you talking about serially processing each file from S3?

Comment: @sve How did you solve the error? Getting the same exception when reading from S3 and making API calls from item processor.

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael Minella mentioned, it might be a choice for you to use [Spring Cloud AWS](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_resource_handling) project to get resources:

```
@Autowired
private ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver;

public void resolveAndLoad() throws IOException {
    Resource[] allTxtFilesInFolder =  this.resourcePatternResolver.getResources("s3://bucket/name/*.txt");
    Resource[] allTxtFilesInBucket =  this.resourcePatternResolver.getResources("s3://bucket/**/*.txt");
    Resource[] allTxtFilesGlobally =  this.resourcePatternResolver.getResources("s3://**/*.txt");
}
```

And then pass the resources to your MultiFileResourcePartitioner to see the exception can be solved.

Comment: I have tried using Spring Cloud and I still have the same error. What i did was passed all the files received to MultiResourcePartitioner and a custom resource to flat file item reader to read the stream. Anything wrong that i am doing here?

Comment: Update: With a little testing over the week end, I have observed that i get this issue only when i introduce a Soap call in my ItemProcessor.

Comment: Without ItemProcessor, it works well? It's weird because the stack trace shows the itemReader get a 'null' resource

Comment: Not with out a Soap Call in Itemprocessor it works well. May be the reader exhausted reading all the data from S3?

Comment: Update: I have moved my WS call to Itemwriter and works fine with out the error.

Comment: I still have this issue and breaking my heads to resolve this. Can some one please help asap? I guess while the job is running using multiresource partitioner the inputstreams are being opened by one thread and other thread is closing this but again this is my opinion. How can i handle this issue. I have implemented all the above which was suggested.

Comment: and this issue is similar to [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2051) . But that post suggested to use MultiResourcePartitioner which I am using `org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.NonTransientFlatFileException: Unable to read from resource: [Amazon s3 resource [bucket='xxxx' and object='20150416022308_xxxxx.dat']] Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`