# FlatFileItemWriter to call WS and write response to a file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am calling a WS from a FlatFileItemWriter. The web service calls are successful but i also want to write to response to a file simultaneously. How can i achieve this. Below is my code for calling WS

```
@Inject  private Webservice webservice;

 public void write(List<? extends Pojo> list) throws Exception {

 for (Pojo pojo : list) {

 webservice.putrequest(list);

}
```

Comment: Did anyone get a chance to look at my question?

Comment: Writer is not a good place for anything else than writing, would suggest to move WS call to Processor instead and pass the response wrapped inside the travelling object to writer for respective write. Check this spring link for details on flatfileitemwriter http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html

Comment: The main intention behind calling the WS in an itemwriter is to utilize the chunk capabilities for example calling webservice with 1k items in a single shot. I am getting IOExceptions as the processing of WS call takes a while and the reads timeout. Whats best for the performance in such scenarios?

Comment: So basically your problem is IOException & not how to write !!! If yes pls share your writer code & error stacktrace for more info.

Comment: Mainly my concern is the IOex and also to utilize writer to write responses to a file incase my WS call is in ItemWriter plus performance  . My other IO exception error is posted here [IOException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205122/spring-batch-multifileresourcepartitioner-caused-by-java-net-socketexceptio) `ItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Person>,ItemStream {
    @Inject webserviceDao;     
    @Override
public void write(List<? extends Person> list) {
List<Person> PersonList = (List<Person>) list;
response = webserviceDao.sendRequest(PersonList );
/reponse to file}`

Comment: For socketException you have to play around with readTimeout & connectTimeout with something like this :-                                     <bean class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"
            p:readTimeout="2000"
            p:connectTimeout="2000" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>   But again i suggest you to review your current project architecture.

Comment: The main exception that i mentioned in my other post says "unable to read from resource" which is not the same as webservice time out more of NonTransientException. thoughts?

Comment: Pls check  2nd para of exception stacktrace its socketException which resulting in "unable to read" :- Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)</i>

Comment: Thanks Avis . This means the file i read gets a resource from Aws s3 and a ws call both use http methods . Either of them can cause this error?

Comment: Thats correct, http is base carrier.